# adonis2: marginal tests for models with main effects AND interaction terms

Tags: r, vegan

My study design has three factors that all interact and I have 16S microbial community data. I am trying to have a model in which I can test for the effects of all the main effects, (A, B, C), the two-way interactions (A:B, A:C, B:C) and the three-way interaction (A:B:C), without specifying order of the factors (as is the default). Ideally, I would have a similar output as a Type III Anova.

Using marginal tests (`by = "margin"`) doesn't work because when it is written like that it only shows the significance of the interaction terms (without the main effects).

Below is a reproduceable example with only two factors.

```
library(vegan)
data(dune)
data(dune.env)
adonis2(dune~Moisture*Manure,
        data = dune.env,
        permutations = 999,
        method = "bray",
        strata = dune.env$Management,
        by = "margin")
```

output:

```
Permutation test for adonis under reduced model
Marginal effects of terms
Blocks:  strata 
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

adonis2(formula = dune ~ Moisture * Manure, data = dune.env, permutations = 999, method = "bray", by = "margin", strata = dune.env$Management)
                Df SumOfSqs      R2      F Pr(>F)
Moisture:Manure  4   0.4678 0.10881 0.9213  0.451
Residual         8   1.0154 0.23620              
Total           19   4.2990 1.00000
```

same is true when the interaction is written out instead

```
adonis2(dune~Moisture+Manure+Moisture:Manure,
        data = dune.env,
        permutations = 999,
        method = "bray",
        strata = dune.env$Management,
        by = "margin")
```

output:

```
Permutation test for adonis under reduced model
Marginal effects of terms
Blocks:  strata 
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

adonis2(formula = dune ~ Moisture + Manure + Moisture:Manure, data = dune.env, permutations = 999, method = "bray", by = "margin", strata = dune.env$Management)
                Df SumOfSqs      R2      F Pr(>F)
Moisture:Manure  4   0.4678 0.10881 0.9213  0.424
Residual         8   1.0154 0.23620              
Total           19   4.2990 1.00000
```

Is there a sound way to go about doing this where I can concurrently test for the main effects as well as their interactions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Marginal tests are called marginal tests because they only test marginal effects. If you have interaction terms, these interactions are marginal, but their component main effects are not marginal and are not tested. There are no "Type III" (funny name) in `adonis2`. Nobody has written those.

Comment: I was wondering if this was a fundamentally "wrong" approach- that makes sense! thank you for answering. Would it make sense to then first test solely for the most complicated interaction and move "down" the list to the main effects only if the interactions are not significant? (A:B:C, A:B+A:B+B:C, A+B+C) I was thinking about using pairwise.adonis2 if any of the interactions proved significant

Comment: @SiwookHwang: no idea. I have never understood "Type III sum of squares" or other SAS types. You better ask someone who understands what these numbered SAS types are.